# Can't delete first Pinyin character in Monaco editor in Edge

Tags: javascript, microsoft-edge, monaco-editor

**monaco-editor version:** 0.16.1
**Browser:** Microsoft Edge
**OS:** Win10 1809

**Steps or JS usage snippet reproducing the issue:**

This has nothing to do with how to use it. In fact, the editor of the official website can reproduce.

1. One character will be retained under Pinyin input method

I am a Chinese developer. I found that when I use the Pinyin input method that comes with the system, I press the delete button after typing a few characters, but the editor always keeps the first letter:

[image](https://storage.live.com/items/51816931BAB0F7A8!12449?authkey=AO7QXpgYo7-5DUU)

2. When switching, there are a lot of unknown characters in the pinyin input.

When you use `Alt`+`Tab` to switch applications and switch back, if you start typing with Pinyin in one to two seconds, a lot of junk characters will be generated. Each time you press a button on the keyboard, a number of characters will be generated.

[image](https://storage.live.com/items/51816931BAB0F7A8!12450?authkey=AO7QXpgYo7-5DUU)

These characters cannot be copied and pasted, so I don't know the meaning of these characters.

---

The above tests are only in the Edge browser and use the Microsoft Pinyin input method.

I didn't make any special settings for the editor because I can completely reproduce it [here](https://microsoft.github.io/monaco-editor/playground.html).

Comment: I made a test in Win 10 1809, MS Edge with Monaco editor 0.16.2 version. I find that Microsoft Chinese pinyin are working correctly and I am not able to produce the above mentioned issues with it. I suggest you to make a test with the 0.16.2 version to check the issue on your side. If it works correctly than you can try to use the latest version of Monaco editor to solve the issue.

Comment: After I tried to upgrade, I still can't solve the problem I encountered. I am using the Edge browser of the EdgeHTML kernel, which is also used in UWP applications. I also found the same problem in the Windows Community Toolkit Sample App.

Comment: This is my testing result with MS Edge. https://imgur.com/a/f4xJC7u For testing purpose, You can try to reset MS Edge and check whether it helps to solve the issue or not. Ref: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4023560/windows-10-what-to-do-if-microsoft-edge-not-working

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I have seen your test result, but your steps seem to be wrong. When deleting text, please do not press the delete key all the time. Just input two chararcters and press delete key twice, you'll see.When switching windows, please be quick and make sure that the input method is in Chinese mode. I mean, enter text immediately after using the shortcut key to switch the window (not the mouse click to switch), and don't waiting.

Comment: I again made a test on 2 machines with Edge. I try to enter only 2 characters and when I remove it. I find that at every press, it is doing something. So it looks like due to that process it stops at first character. I use keyboard shortcuts to switch tabs and I try to enter characters immediately but it did not show any junk characters. If possible for you than try to check any new updates for Edge and if any available than install it and again make a test. It may help to solve this issue.

Comment: The Edge is updated with the system. For this I used two machines, one of which is the latest preview system and the other one with the 1809 upgrade. There are fewer junk characters in the preview system, but unfortunately, the problem persists. Maybe our operation is still a little different.Do you use pinyin when you type after switching windows?

Comment: Yes, I use pinyin while typing after switching the windows. You can try to reset the MS Edge browser to check whether it helps to solve the issue or not.